# How to set JSP response locale in Jetty 7/8?

Tags: jsp, jetty, locale

If I set the HTTP response locale programmatically in a servlet as follows:

```
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws IOException, ServletException
{
    response.setLocale(SOME_LOCALE);
    // .. etc
}
```

Then under Jetty 7 and later, any JSPs trying to read that locale via the expression ${pageContext.response.locale} will get the server's default locale instead of the one set above. If I use Jetty 6 or Tomcat, it works fine.

Here's the full code to demonstrate the problem:

```
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {

    // Use a dummy locale that's unlikely to be the user's default
    private static final Locale TEST_LOCALE = new Locale("abcdefg");

    @Override
    protected void doGet(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response)
        throws IOException, ServletException
    {
        // Set a known response locale
        response.setLocale(TEST_LOCALE);

        // Publish some interesting locales to the JSP as request attributes for debugging
        request.setAttribute("defaultLocale", Locale.getDefault());
        request.setAttribute("testLocale", TEST_LOCALE);

        // Forward the request to our JSP
        getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }
}
```

And the JSP:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Locale Tester</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>Locale Tester</h2>
        <ul>
            <li>pageContext.request.locale = '${pageContext.request.locale}'</li>
            <li>default locale = '<%= request.getAttribute("defaultLocale") %>'</li>
            <li>pageContext.response.locale = '${pageContext.response.locale}' (should be '<%= request.getAttribute("testLocale") %>')</li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

Tomcat returns this (correctly):

```
Locale Tester

    pageContext.request.locale = 'en_AU'
    default locale = 'en_US'
    pageContext.response.locale = 'abcdefg' (should be 'abcdefg')
```

Jetty 7 returns this (wrongly):

```
Locale Tester

    pageContext.request.locale = 'en_AU'
    default locale = 'en_US'
    pageContext.response.locale = 'en_US' (should be 'abcdefg')
```

FWIW, I did all the above testing using the Jetty/Tomcat Maven plugins.

Comment: What happens if you use `new Locale("ru", "ru")` instead of `new Locale("abcdefg")`?

Comment: In that case I get "pageContext.response.locale = 'en_US' (should be 'ru_RU')", in other words I still have the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out via the Jetty mailing list that this is a bug in Jetty 7, which has now [been fixed](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=351039).