# Spring locale: can't get interceptors to work

Tags: java, spring, configuration, locale

I have a jsp file with 2 links which set a property lang to either en or de.
I also have a message that needs to be changed in the corresponding language either english or german.
I have the 2 property files with the codes. I made the configuration file for the locale.
I've tried different combination of classes and properties but I can never get the message changed.

This is my code:

jsp file:

```
Language : <a href="?lang=en">English</a>|<a href="?lang=de">German</a>
   <h3>
      <spring:message code="test" text="default text" />
   </h3>
Current Locale : ${pageContext.response.locale} ---- ${pageContext.request.locale}
```

applicationContext.locale.xml file: (this is imported in applicationContext.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">


<bean id="messageSource"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="WEB-INF/locale/welcome" />
    <property name="cacheSeconds" value="-1" />
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
</bean>

<bean id="localeChangeInterceptor"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
    <property name="paramName" value="lang" />
</bean>

<bean id="localeResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver">
    <property name="defaultLocale" value="en"/>
</bean>

<bean id="urlMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
    <property name="interceptors">
        <list>
            <ref bean="localeChangeInterceptor"/>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

I have 2 property files:
welcome.properties and welcome_de.properties. Both have a code test and different values to it.

The problem is if I set the default Locale it will always take that. If I don't set it the locale resolver will take the locale of the request.

I can't set the locale of the response to be taken from the url parameter.

Do you have any suggestions?

Thanks :)

Comment: If you are using Jetty then check this [Jetty related bug][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6543525/how-to-set-jsp-response-locale-in-jetty-7-8

Answer (score 0):

Check your code against the project you can download from the [MVC Simplifications in Spring 3.0](http://blog.springsource.com/2009/12/21/mvc-simplifications-in-spring-3-0/)

https://src.springframework.org/svn/spring-samples/mvc-basic/trunk/